# Snowflake - how to display column name using function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I did not get much help from Snowflake documentation about how I can take give column names using snowflake functions.

I have automated report which will do calculation for the given dates. here it is

```
select
  sum(case when logdate = to_date(dateadd('day', - 10, '2019-11-14')) then eng_fees + data_fees end) AS to_date(dateadd('day', - 10, '2019-11-14'))
from myTable
where logdate = '2019-11-04'
```

I am getting following output for my **column name** below

```
to_date(dateadd('day', - 10, '2019-11-14'))
100
```

My **expected output** for my **column name**

```
2019-11-04
100
```

how can I print expected date as column name in Snowflake?

Comment: What is the use case? Is it just for printing in the Snowflake web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is using an AS to name your column.  Snowflake will treat that as a literal, not a calculation.  In order to do what you're requesting inside a function, you'll need to use a Javascript Function, I think.  This will allow you to dynamically build the SQL Statement with your calculated column name predefined.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js.html

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have column name expressions at all _within the database_. You have to predeclare the column names with UDTFs (SQL and JavaScript) and scalar functions don't affect column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have dynamic column names without using external functionality (or `TASK` scheduling).

You can create a JavaScript Stored Procedure that generates a `VIEW` where the column names can be set by dynamic parameters / expressions.

The normal way of handling this is to use a reporting tool that can display your fixed column result set with dynamic headers or run dynamic SQL altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 paths of getting close to what you want:

1) you can simply use UNION to have your headers displayed as the first row and change the actual column aliases into 1....N - so that they provide the number of column - this is going to be the fastest and the cheapest

2) you can use dynamic SQL to generate a query that will have your alias names dynamically filled and then simply run it (and you can use to example PIVOT to construct such query)

Comment: could you provide an example of your first approach.